# Get number of image files and switching between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've a directory containing a few image files [for example 4 files], I want to get the number of images existing in the directory and then show the first image and allow users to switch between images using some controller elements and show the number of the image that is now showing between it.
For example:
I've 4 images and page shows the first image and this text " << 1/4 >> " and when user clicks on the next button it shows the next image and text changes to " << 2/4 >> " and ...
Can you show me the foundation of work? I mean you can just tell me what I've to do (not needed to attach codes). I use AngularJS in my page now, But if it's needed I can use JQuery too ( If it's not possible to do that using AngularJS ).

This is my html page although I think it's not very helpful:

```
<?php require ('functions.php');mob_check(); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fa-IR" data-ng-app="projects" data-ng-controller="projects_controller">
    <!-- Website design by Mohsen_Nirouzad -->

    <head>
        <!-- Adding meta information -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="Mohsen Nirouzad - http://AproZ.ir">
        <!-- defining stylesheets DO NOT delete the bellow codes if you don't have enough knowledge of web design -->
        <!-- I used w3data.min.js for javascript templating engine so you've to change the bellow information in script tag -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{{page_title}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/w3rtl.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/imagehover.min.css">
        <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            img {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }

            #second_imglist {
                position: relative;
                right: -100px;
            }

            #squares {
                position: absolute;
                top: 630px;
                right: 400px;
            }

            #imgset {
                position: relative;
                top: 30px;
            }

            #img_controllers {
                position: relative;
                top: 90px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php require 'variables/date.php'; ?>
            <nav class="w3-sidenav w3-white" style="width:15%" id="mySidenav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="english w3-medium">
                    <?php echo (date('l d m Y')); ?>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-medium"><span><?php $today=persianday(date("l"));echo $today;?></span>   <span><?php echo (date('d m Y')); ?></span></a>
                <a href="engineers.php" id="first_menuitem">مهندسین مشاور سرابن</a>
                <a href="projects.php" class="w3-no-opacity w3-large">پروژه ها</a>
                <a href="research.php">پژوهش</a>
                <a href="contact.php">ارتباط با ما</a>
                <a href="members.php">اعضا</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="english">English</a>
                <div class="w3-center" style="margin-top:50px;">
                    <a href="index.php" id="linkimg"><img src="assets/img/logo.jpg"></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <?php /*
    if ($_GET['v']==='desktopview'){
        echo '<div data-ng-include="\'variables/sidenav.php\'"></div>';
    } elseif ($_GET['v']==='mobileview'){
        echo '<div data-ng-include="\'variables/sidenav-responsive.html\'"></div>';
    }
    if ($_GET['v']==='desktopview'){
        echo '<div id="main" style="margin-right: calc(15% + 100px)" class="w3-row-padding">';
    } elseif ($_GET['v']==='mobileview'){
        echo '<div id="main" class="w3-row-padding">';
    }
    if ($_GET['v']==='mobileview'){
        echo '<span class="w3-opennav w3-text-black w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()" id="openNav">&#9776;</span>';
    }
    */?>
                <div id="main" style="margin-right: calc(15% + 100px)" class="w3-row-padding">
                    <div class="w3-col s6">
                        <div data-ng-include="'variables/logo1.html'"></div>
                        <div class="w3-row w3-margin-top" id="imgset">
                            <div class="w3-col s6" id="first_imglist">
                                <div>
                                    <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage(1)">
                                        <img data-ng-src="{{img1}}" alt="example-image">
                                        <figcaption>
                                            <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                            <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                        </figcaption>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage()"><img src="{{img1}}" data-ng-click="selectImage()" alt="example-image">
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                        <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                </figure>
                                <div>
                                    <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage()"><img src="{{img1}}" alt="example-image">
                                        <figcaption>
                                            <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                            <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                        </figcaption>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage()"><img src="{{img1}}" alt="example-image">
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                        <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                </figure>

                            </div>
                            <div class="w3-col s6" id="second_imglist">
                                <div>
                                    <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage()"><img src="{{img1}}" alt="example-image">
                                        <figcaption>
                                            <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                            <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                        </figcaption>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage()"><img src="{{img1}}" alt="example-image">
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                        <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                </figure>

                                <div>
                                    <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage()"><img src="{{img1}}" alt="example-image">
                                        <figcaption>
                                            <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                            <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                        </figcaption>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <figure class="imghvr-zoom-out-right" data-ng-click="selectImage()"><img src="{{img1}}" alt="example-image">
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <h3>سلام دنیا!</h3>
                                        <p>این یک متن نمونه است!</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                                </figure>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-col s6 w3-center" id="img_controllers">
                        <img data-ng-src="{{selectedImage}}" data-ng-if="selectImage" style="width:100% !important;height:100% !important;margin-top:100px" class="w3-hover-opacity w3-round-small">
                        <div>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="increasenumber()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a> {{activenumber}}/{{imagesnumber}}
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="decreasenumber()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="remove()" class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-ng-include="'variables/footer.html'"></div>
                <div class="w3-center" id="squares">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></a>
                </div>
                <script src="assets/js/projects.js"></script>
                <script>
                    <?php
    if ($_GET['v']==='mobileview'){
        echo 'function w3_open() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "25%";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25%";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = \'none\';
    }

    function w3_close() {
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "0%";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
    }';
    }
    ?>
                </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

projects.js:

```
// Start angularjs application
var application = angular.module('projects', []);

// Setting conroller
application.controller('projects_controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.page_title = 'پروژه ها',
        $scope.img1 = 'assets/img/example-image.jpg',
        $scope.selectImage = function () {
            $scope.selectedImage = $scope.img1;
        };
    //$scope.selectedImage = $scope.img1;
    $scope.imagesnumber = 12,
        $scope.firstnumber = 1,
        $scope.activenumber = $scope.firstnumber,
        $scope.increasenumber = function () {
            if ($scope.activenumber === $scope.imagesnumber) {
                $scope.activenumber = $scope.firstnumber;
            } else {
                $scope.activenumber++;
            }
        }
    $scope.decreasenumber = function () {
            if ($scope.activenumber === $scope.firstsnumber) {
                $scope.activenumber = $scope.imagesnumber;
            } else {
                $scope.activenumber--;
            }
        },
        $scope.remove = function () {
            document.getElementById('img_controllers').style.display = 'none';
        };
});
```

Comment: please add the html to the question

Comment: you need webserver that provides information about your images and images itself to clients.

Comment: @Jayababu I added the code to my post.
Maxx I cannot understand what are you speaking about. I want to do it with some JS/AngularJS codes, Do you mean I need some server-side scripting for my page?

Comment: hope this helps you
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write image pagination static logic,I think it can help you.

**HTML**

```
<img src="first image url" id="1_image" class="image-element">
<img src="second image url" id="2_image" class="image-element">
<img src="third image url" id="3_image" class="image-element">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="1" class="pagination-link">
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="2" class="pagination-link">
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="3" class="pagination-link">
```

**JQuery**

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      //Hide all images in load event
      $('.image-element').hide();

      //show default one image in load event.
      $('#1').show();

      $(.pagination-link).on('click','.pagination-link',function{
           //Hide all images using class.
           $('.image-element').hide('slow');
           var link_id = $(this).id();
           //show particular one image using id
           $('#'+link_id+"_image").show('slow');
      })
    });
```